# Oracle check constraint to enforce only numbers and full stops

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I want to enforce a check constraint on an Oracle varchar column so that the only valid strings are composed of :

- just integers with no spaces or
- just integers with no spaces and with single full stops between some integers

So these strings would be valid :

- 1
- 12
- 123
- 1.2
- 12.3
- 1.2.3
- 11.2.3
- 11.52.3
- 1.52.13

And these would be invalid

- foo
- 1foo
- 1.foo
- 1 1
- .1
- 1.
- 1f1

I've looked at using a UDF to do this if it were straightforward to do it with Regex's or some sort of lash together with TRANSLATE or similar I think I would prefer that.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Something like: `check (regexp_like(the_column, '[0-9]+[0-9\.]*'))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like

```
alter table TBL add constraint TBL_COL_FMT
  check (regexp_like(COL, '^\d+(\.\d+)*$'));
```

where the regular expression means one or more digits (`\d+`) followed
by zero or more groups of a single dot and one or more digits (`(\.\d+)*`).

Comment: `regexp_like(COL, '^\d+(\.\d+)*$')` would be a bit faster.

Comment: @Egor Skriptunoff: You are right, it avoids unnecessary backtracking, just edited my answer accordingly. Thanks.